# Having a map as a Maven plugin parameter

Tags: plugins, parameters, maven, dictionary

I am using maven 3 and I want to pass in a type Map as a parameter.

I have this in my mojo at the moment:

```
/**
 * @parameter expression="${rep.env}" alias="environments"
 * @required
 */
private Map<String,String[]> environments = null;
```

I am passing in this during the configuration:

```
                <environments>
                    <Testing>
                        <param>
                            unit
                        </param>
                    </Testing>
                </environments>
```

It is complaining that it is missing the parameter environments, are you allowed to do this in maven?

Answer (score 7):

Did you try to just remove the `alias="environments"` attribute?

Another point is that I am not sure that Maven will allow you to set a Map of `String[]` as key. I think it will only deal with `Map<String, String>` ([the page here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) only shows a basic Map example).

Eventually, what you can do is to allow comma-separated value instead of a `String[]`:

```
<configuration>
    <environments>
        <one>a,b,c</one>
        <two>d</two>
    </environments>
</configuration>
```

and then, when you have to deal with your values, you simply split your String to get a String array (you can use [Apache Commons-lang StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) to do that easily):

```
/**
 * @parameter expression="${rep.env}"
 * @required
 */
private Map<String, String> environments = null;

public void foo() {
    String[] values = StringUtils.split(environments.get("one"), ',');
    // values == {"a", "b", "c"};
}
```